# How does one safely fail a deadlift?

Tags: deadlifts

There are ample guides for other power lifting exercises like squat or bench press, but none I can easily find for dl from a reliable source. Could someone explain how to?

Comment: Number one thing to look out for is your back - in this situation it's common to see people lose form or relax their core muscles. Be sure to keep your spine in a neutral position and core activated until the weight is on the ground.

Answer (score 6):

If you feel a deadlift going wrong, put it down or drop it.

Comment: Is there anything to keep in mind while dropping ?

Comment: I mean it's a heavy object and it might bounce or roll, so I'd try to avoid letting it hit me or anything else it could break. But if I'm failing so bad I have to drop it then I'm probably concerned about other things. I edited my answer to add the possibility of putting it down, which generally happens fast but with enough control to prevent it rolling away or landing on me.